# Добавление DataValidation из Python в Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, excel-формулы

Использую библиотеку openpyxl. Пытаюсь добавить проверку данных в эксель:

```
dv = DataValidation(type="custom", formula1='=AND(LEN(A3)=6;VALUE(LEFT(A3;2))<12)', allow_blank=True)
```

Но при открытии экселя, ругается что книга повреждена и пытается восстановить ее.
Сама формула при добавлении вручную в самой книге работает без проблем

> =И(ДЛСТР(H7)=2;ЗНАЧЕН(ЛЕВСИМВ(H7;1))>2)

Если использовать =AND(LEN(A3)=6 и =VALUE(LEFT(A3;2))<12) отдельно друг от друга то все работает так же. Я так понимаю, что проблема именно в объединении двух формул, но подружить их так и не могу

Весь код:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
wb = Workbook()
ws =wb.create_sheet()
dv = DataValidation(type="custom", 
formula1='=AND(LEN(A3)=6;VALUE(LEFT(A3;2))<12)', allow_blank=True)
ws.add_data_validation(dv)
dv.add(ws.cell(row = 3, column= 1))
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Обманул, судя по всему проблема как раз со второй формулой:  =VALUE(LEFT(A3;2))<12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается в подобных формулах

> LEFT(A3;2)

Используется не ";" а ",". Вот и все решение для тех, кто так же потерял на это время

Comment: Собственно, так же и между формул... Никаких ";"